# How to digitally sign emails in the Mail app in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I used to use Windows Live Mail before upgrading but now I'm using the Mail app that comes with Windows 8, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to sign emails with a digital signature.

Before I could sign and verify signed emails when I received them, how to do so in the Mail app?

(if it helps, my private key is already installed)

Comment: Yes, digital signatures to authenticate users, S/MIME.

Comment: You will likely have to use a desktop application. The Mail application at this time does not support this feature. You should still be able to install `Windows Live Mail` contained within `Windows Essentials 2012` on Windows 8.

Comment: I see, no wonder I couldn't find anything about it anywhere; I hope they add support for it in the near future. Thank you.

Comment: @Carla - They added several versions since the Windows 8 RTM build.  Microsoft has proven they want to make the Modern UI applications as functional as they can be.  For the time being the desktop application can still be used.  There isn't a reason you couldn't use both, depending on if you "download" the emails or simply use IMAP/Exchange, if your downloading the emails through POP3 syncing between two applications would be a problem.

Comment: Others are having similar issue too http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-ecoms/mail-app-digital-certificate/fd18864f-8d63-4b77-bd40-de0ea42d7bfe

Answer (score 2):

After exploring the application, I found that there is no such functionality available in current Windows Mail metro app at this time. Even after trying for Certificate Installation process suggested by Microsoft isn't so helpful. So you can go with desktop apps, like Microsoft Outlook if it is must for you.